# Where does the cool air come from?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cooling

I found [this gif/video](https://s2.glbimg.com/Qim0lezrdCUrAPTxStCka_2NtGQ=/0x0:1286x960/600x0/smart/filters:gifv():strip_icc()/i.s3.glbimg.com/v1/AUTH_08fbf48bc0524877943fe86e43087e7a/internal_photos/bs/2019/y/i/Tg5Vd4RVAnLZ7peytBxA/apple-16-inch-macbook-pro-advanced-thermal-design-111319.gif) on a blog post about the Macbook Pro 2019. It shows its cooling system.

I am curious about how this works, because in the animation, cool air comes from the side, but there is no vent on the sides nor the bottom of this device chassis.

Anything I'm missing here? How does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ventilation slots on the sides of that Macbook Pro 16 model. Here's the 3D model view:

[image]

Comment: And on most older models, the cool air comes from the little spaces between the keys of the keyboard